# Python replace string with random digits in multiple files

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

This code reads files from a directory and replaces string "400432" with a random 6 digits generated by python, builds a script and executes.

Each file should have a unique random 6 digits with corresponding script. File 1: 123456 and script 123456.sh, file 2: 775463 and script 775463.sh, etc.

The problem is when multiple files are present the 123456 is written into all files and only 123456.sh is created. I am not sure how to loop this and it's been 3 years since I've used python.

Struggling to finish this up. Thanks for any help!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import stat
import fileinput
import glob
import sys
import re
import random
import subprocess
import string


##############################################################
# Generates random numbers and replaces in WSP files
##############################################################

def random_digits(y):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for x in range(y))
rand = str(random_digits(6))
_replace_re = re.compile("400432")
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/home/mark/WSP_IN/"):
    for file in filenames:
        file = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
        head, tail = os.path.split(file)
    tempfile = file + ".temp"
        with open(tempfile, "w") as target:
            with open(file) as source:
                for line in source:
                    line = _replace_re.sub(rand, line)
                    target.write(line)
            os.rename(tempfile, file)
##############################################################
# Creates script that builds ship to based on random numbers
##############################################################

s = open('/usr/local/bin/wsp_scripts/' + rand + '.sh', 'wb+')

##############################################################
# Define responses as string arguments rather than text
##############################################################

data = '/usr/local/bin/wsp_scripts/'
ext = '.sh'
space = ' ';
script = 'exec ${B}/pro5 -c${CF}'
pathx = ' -m2048 -q ${P} - '
swfile = str(tail+space)
swship = str(rand)
sscript = str(script)
spathx = str(pathx)
shell = str(data+rand+ext)

##############################################################
# Write static text and arguments into file
##############################################################

s.write('#!/bin/bash' + '\n')
s.write('#termsoa=/soatermsystem' + '\n'),
s.write('PATH=$PATH:/usr/basic:/usr/basic/util' + '\n')
s.write('B=/usr/local/basis/pro5' + '\n')
s.write('P=/usr5/prog/utils/SO/EDIshipbuild' + '\n')
s.write('CF=/usr/local/basis/pro5/config.bbx'+ '\n')
s.write('TERMCAP=${B}/termcap' + '\n')
s.write('export PATH TERM TERMCAP' + '\n')
s.write('umask 0' + '\n')
s.write('cd /usr/basic' + '\n')
s.write(sscript+spathx+swfile+rand)

st = os.stat(shell)
os.chmod(shell, st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)
s.close()

##############################################################
# Import script just created and execute
##############################################################

cmd = '/usr/local/bin/wsp_scripts/' + rand + '.sh'

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
out, err = p.communicate()
result = out.split('\n')
for lin in result:
   if not lin.startswith('#'):
       print(lin)
s.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `rand` and create your .sh file outside of the `for` loop. If you want to redefine `rand` for each file move its definition into the inner for loop. Same goes for the .sh file creation.

Which I think would look like this.

```
def random_digits(y):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for x in range(y))

_replace_re = re.compile("400432")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/home/mark/WSP_IN/"):
    for file in filenames:
        rand = str(random_digits(6))
        file = os.path.join(dirpath, file)
        head, tail = os.path.split(file)
        tempfile = file + ".temp"
        with open(tempfile, "w") as target:
            with open(file) as source:
                for line in source:
                    line = _replace_re.sub(rand, line)
                    target.write(line)
        os.rename(tempfile, file)
        ##############################################################
        # Creates script that builds ship to based on random numbers
        ##############################################################

        s = open('/usr/local/bin/wsp_scripts/' + rand + '.sh', 'wb+')
```

Comment: This works in modifying the files and replacing the text with a unique number, scripts are also unique. However, only 1 script is written to and the other is blank. I must need another loop for the s.write?

Comment: You'll need to add your writes in just after the open at the same indentation level.

Comment: Thank You Stephen! Everything works except the scripts run all at once and i need them to run sequentially or after each script finishes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know , if using 6 digits is a requirement or not?

```
import time
def random_digits(y):
    return int(time.time())
```

It will return the 10 digit timestamp and will always be unique.

Let me know, if it helps!